# Embedded Ruby Integration w/ Web Server (as a php Replacement)

Tags: ruby, erb, embedded-ruby

I'm looking to make some relatively simple pages with some relatively small pieces of dynamic content inside.

I have looked into embedded Ruby as a potential alternative to php in this situation, and it looks rather interesting. Which implementation should I use, and how should I integrate this with a web server such as Apache? In other words, what is analogous to something like mod_php or php through CGI?

My primary goal here is convenience. I would like this to require less effort to implement and maintain. Also, I am looking to have access to things like HTTP request parameters and other such goodies in a convenient format (i.e. if I use CGI, I don't want to be parsing argv manually).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution would be to run an application server via [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) and have Apache proxy to it. Your application can use whatever HTTP and templating libraries you like. Take a look at [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) if you're not familiar. It's very lightweight and flexible.